# Contar registros que antecedem o selecionado na consulta sql server, mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, postgresql, select

Tenho uma duvida: Como faço para saber quantos registros tem antes de um valor selecionado.

> Por exemplo:

```
 Select * from cidades where nome= 'SAO PAULO' ORDER BY nome
```

Imaginando que a tabela cidades tenha 500 registros e eu pesquisei por SAO PAULO, eu quero saber quantas cidades tem antes de SAO PAULO na minha busca, 
 levanto em conta o ORDER BY nome

Comment: É `sql-server`, `postgresql` ou `mysql`? A forma de fazer em cada SGBD é diferente.

Comment: De preferencia sql-server, mas preciso dos 3

Comment: Basicamente é o que está no post linkado acima, é um `SELECT count(*) AS posicao WHERE nome < "São Paulo"`

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza veja o post que eu linkei acima, tem exatamente o que você disse. Um sub pra achar a pontuação (no caso seria o ID da cidade) e outro externo pra rankear

Comment: Consegui no Sql-server SELECT COUNT(COD)- 1 AS TOTAL FROM  CODMUNICIPIO WHERE CIDADE <= '" + CidadeEmpresa + "', Muito obrigado pelas dicas, ajudou muito